# Getting Column name from CSV file and loading as data in DB using control file

Tags: csv, batch-file, sql-loader

My Control file is like this:

```
OPTIONS (skip=1) 
LOAD DATA

APPEND

INTO TABLE Temp_Wide

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","

TRAILING NULLCOLS

(

nothing        boundfiller,

Date_Recorded "TO_DATE(:nothing || :Date_Recorded , 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')",

Millitm CHAR,

nothing1        boundfiller,

TEMPERATURE CHAR,

nothing2        boundfiller,

Tagname (Name of Column4 in input CSV)

)
```

and in my batch script i am calling the control file and an input CSV file.

I need to get insert tagname data as name of the column4 from that particular input CSV, but I'm not sure of how to do so.

Comment: Who's in control of the control files? Will they always be formatted the same way? Right now, `tagname` is on line 13(index 12), will it always be on that line?

Comment: Yes, Tagname is always on that line. Column4 name is different for different input CSV files. I am loading data into 1 db table from many input CSV's. Remaining all columns are same in input CSV except Column4. So i need to load the column4 name of CSV as tagname data in db table.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the column name using something like this:

```
private string getColName(string pathToCSV, int colIndex1Based)
{
    string retval = string.Empty;//getting a variable ready to host the return value
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToCSV))//read the data file
    {
        string currentLine = string.Empty;//just initializing a var
        if ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)//if the line isn't null
        {
            retval = currentLine.Split(',')[colIndex1Based - 1];//split the line using the delimiter, and pick the column you want.
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

.

```
string colname = getColName(@"C:\temp\myFMlog.txt", 4);
```